# Installing windows updates remotely, using PowerShell. (some PowerCLI)

Tags: windows, powershell, powercli, windows-update

I am having a problem with a script for remote windows updates.
My goal: update all the windows servers, without using WSUS or SCCM, from PowerShell without having to log into all of them and start the update process.

For my script I am using powercli and PSWindowsUpdate modules.
For test purposes I am using a single host in the $hostname variable.

So here is what I have.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HostName {Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate} -Verbose -Credential $Cred
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HostName {Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false} -Verbose -Credential $Cred
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HostName -ScriptBlock {Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -IgnoreUserInput -AcceptAll -AutoReboot -Confirm:$FALSE -Verbose | Out-File C:\Setup\PSWindowsUpdate.log } -credential $cred
Get-Content \\$HostName\c$\Setup\PSWindowsUpdate.log
```

After running the script everything works from the shut down, snapshot, power on but I can't install any updates.
I am getting the error below :

```
WARNING: To perform some operations you must run an elevated Windows PowerShell console.
WARNING: Can't access to machine "hostName". Try use: winrm qc
```

As I was searching I see that I can not make any elevation in PowerShell itself and I am reading some posts about running a CMD bat to start PowerShell in elevated rights.
It is not a problem for me to copy to every windows server the update script and have a batch to run it in elevated rights but is this the only way?

I will do the batch solution to see what I can achieve but is there any other solution in the problem I am facing?
Has anyone tried that out?

Thank you very much for your time!
I am also open for any comment on my code or fixes!

Comment: You need to only include code for a [mcve]... only the last 6 lines of your code are relevant to your question. As the rest works fine, there's no need to include it, having a huge chunk of code like you have just puts people off looking at it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JamesC. I just edited the code with the part that gives me the error. I just wanted to provide what I was doing with my script if someone wants to see the full script.

Comment: Now with the batch file I have to press the accept UAC to run the powershell with elevated privileges but I don't want that. Is there a way to bypass that UAC without disabling it from the O.S.? I am reading about schedule tasks and I know that I can do that as many of my scripts that produce reports are running like that. Is the scheduler the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

If Admin right, elevated prompts are your issue, the following may help you.

PS Code to check if running as an Administrator. If not, It will relaunch as an Administrator.

```
If (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    $Arguments = "& '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "'"
    Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $Arguments
    Break
}
```

You will also likely need to modify `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin` at `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\` in the Registry

-

Here is a simple BAT file that will will get around the PS Execution policy and then launch the PS Script (Assuming they are named the same).

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell" /T REG_SZ /V ExecutionPolicy /D Unrestricted /F

Start PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
```

Add the end of your PS Script you can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force`  to set the execution policy back to restricted or what you have ti set to.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to import modules on remote machines using `Invoke-Command`. There's a security function that doesn't allow you to do it. You might try running the following to see if you're more successful at importing a new module.

```
$myPsSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $HostName
Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -PSSession $myPsSession
```

Comment: Hi Nixphoe your answer does not give me a solution as I need to run the PowerShell session in "administrator mode". 
I added two scripts the one that unregisters any previous scheduled task with the same name and creates a new one that will run the actual script in elevated rights as system user.
That solution worked for me fine.
Thank you tho for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I went with the task scheduler solution as it seems easier.

I created a script named WUpdates.ps1

```
$Timestamp=((Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm'))
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Verbose
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false -Verbose
Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -IgnoreUserInput -AcceptAll -AutoReboot -Confirm:$FALSE -Verbose | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Setup\WUpdates\PSWindowsUpdate_$Timestamp.log
```

and a script to create a schedule task named WinUpdateScheduler.ps1

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "WindowsUpdates" -Confirm:$False    
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Argument '-f "C:\Setup\WUpdates\WUpdates.ps1"'
$Trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddSeconds(30)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -RunLevel Highest -User system -TaskName "WindowsUpdates" -Description "Running Windows updates."
```

then in the main script I call the schedule script and have my updates installed.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HostName { c:\setup\WUpdates\WinUpdateScheduler.ps1 } -Credential $Cred
```

If anyone want the full script I can provide it.
As of the Nixphoe and Backin answers, I will check them and I will come back later to comment on them.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName Test-1 -Script { ipmo PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log } 
-Confirm:$false –Verbose
```

https://4sysops.com/archives/install-windows-updates-remotely-with-the-powershell/

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.